# Ubuntu with high resolution computer have very small title or header bar

Tags: hp, 16.10, display-resolution

I have HP Envy laptop (15.6 inch with high resolution 1080P ). I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 and I find many application looks too small. I tried to increase the overall font of the system, but still header and title of the apps did not get increased.

For example, for chrome, search bar and title are too small.
Editors like sublime, brackets have side bar too small.

Did anyone also face the similar issues and were able to resolve this ?

[image]

Please notice the header bar of chrome, it's too small. Even searchbar is too small. Same is the case with many application like sublime, brackets etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `System Settings`, and select the `Displays` settings, you'll see there's a place to set the menu and title bar size...

[image]

You might also try `Unity Tweak Tool` and `Tweak Tool`. Here's a screenshot of `Tweak Tool`, and a HiDPI setting that might help...

[image]

Comment: Thanks @heynnema for suggestion but I already had tried that and it didn't work. On increasing the scale value, it increase everything except header bar, title bar. I have added image as well now in my question.

Comment: Really? Are you using the standard Ubuntu themes, or a custom theme that you downloaded from the Internet.

Comment: This is the default theme provided on installing Ubuntu.

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Comment: @RajeevJayaswal You need to close (kill the actual process) and re-open Chrome and other applications to have the new settings take effect. Chrome and other programs don't exactly respect scaling settings too well

Comment: @KazWolfe - I tried all the possible option. It seems to be the bug ( not sure if it is issues with application or ubuntu ). There was somework around to fix this issues for sublime text editor. Could not find any workaround for chrome and other apps.

Comment: @RajeevJayaswal did you try `Tweak Tool`?

Comment: I tried with Unity Tweak tool, it increase size of everything except for those applications having issues.

Comment: Tweak Tool is the only one that I saw with a specific HiDPI window scaling option. You might still try it. If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!